# With a 100Mbits hosting port speed, will 100 users downloading simultaneously each get 1Mbits?

Tags: web-hosting, vps, looking-for-hosting

I have a file sharing site on shared hosting.  I'm looking to upgrade it to a VPS, but I have a question about the network speed I will get.

If I purchase a plan with 100Mbits port speed, would 100 users download at the same time each be provided with 1 Mbits speed?